# Display <div> behind other div

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` (parent, e.g. 100px x 100px) and other `<div>`s (children, e.g. four squares of 50px x 50px) inside the parent.

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="ch1">...</div>
  <div id="ch2">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

The children fill the parent entirely. Now, I want to show and hide the text in the parent, but I want it to be displayed *behind* the children. If I just do:

```
<div id="parent">TEXT
  <div id="ch1">...</div>
  <div id="ch2">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

it breaks the children layout. `z-index: -1` does not work. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: could you make the `z-index` of the child divs `2`, and the parent `z-index:1`?

Comment: a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be helpful. As well as your CSS...

Comment: What do you mean by 'I want to show and hide the text in the parent'

Comment: This is what I use whenever I forgot about div positioning: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: Two down-votes? Please don't be so cruel : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you *could* position each of the inner divs using absolute position, it makes more sense to me to position the text absolutely rather than the boxes. Consider:

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent"><span>Text</span>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent{
    width:105px;
    height:105px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}

#parent div{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;
}

#parent span{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Eqd4j/

This method is probably a bit more flexible than setting each child div to be positioned absolutely.

Comment: This places the text above the child div, not behind them as ask in the question. "but I want it to be displayed behind the children"

Comment: Then just set z-index: -1; on the span. Simples.

Answer (score 5):

CSS:

```
#parent{
    position:relative;
}

#ch1{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

#ch2{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:50px;
}

#ch3{
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:0;
}

#ch4{
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way -- Use absolute positioning.